# Displaying a form on one line, using Ruby on Rails and Simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

HTML:

```
<div id="monitor" style="height: 22px;">
    <%= @event_status.video %> 
    <%= simple_form_for @new_event_status do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :audio %>
        <%= f.input :video %>
        <%= f.input :notes, :as => :string %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#monitor #new_event_status .input {display : inline-block;}
```

It will only work if I take away the message that displays above the form.  How can I get it all on one line.

HTML Produced:

```
<body scroll="no">

    <div id="wrapper" style="height: auto; width: auto; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 90px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">

<div id="monitor" style="height: 22px;"> 
    Last status:  Audio: Good  Video: Good
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/event_statuses" class="simple_form new_event_status" id="new_event_status" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HDyghGBaq8WB3a2wIEhN+FAHRUWzWBc0Bj4Vz0IVsx4="></div>
        <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Audio and Video is good">
        <input name="event_status[audio]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional" id="event_status_audio" name="event_status[audio]" type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
        <input name="event_status[video]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional" id="event_status_video" name="event_status[video]" type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
        <input class="string optional" id="event_status_notes" name="event_status[notes]" size="50" type="text">
        <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Event Status">
</form></div>
```

There is more HTML of the page, but the rest is just creating a flash gui for my program.  This should display above the GUI produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#FORM_ID input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

just tried it with sign in form for Devise, Devise also uses simple_form and it works.

[image]

**Note!** this won't work if your inputs are inside of another element. In this case you'll have to apply inline-block to that element. For exemple:

**html:**

```
<form id="login">
  <div class="my-input">
    <your input here>
  </div>
</form>
```

**css:**

```
#FORM_ID .my-input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Ok so i found my problem,  I didnt include a message I had at the top becuase I didn't think it would cause problems(Silly me).  I added the message to my original post.  When I take the message away it works just fine.  How can i get the message AND the form on the same line?

Comment: pastie.org - paste you full page html in there.. I think this might be an issue where a div or other element is not closed as it should be or it is closed twice.

Comment: I added the HTML i thought was relevant the rest is javascript for a flash GUI.  It should appear above all that, which works fine.  its just that the form is kicked down a line

Comment: div wrapper is wrapping your form too? I see a div starts but is not ending, is it a wrapper for all site or only the message?

Comment: I am adding here comments just get the "move this discussion to chat" link :)

Comment: as here we won't do much of a thing

Comment: yes it wraps the page to give room for an advertisement at the bottom if there is one.  That is all done by RoR, and it does close.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33926/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-user1977840)